# How to get value approximately from a key in mapReduce mongoose?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I have some documents in mongodb such as:

```
{
        "_id" : ObjectId("587f41ffb5ffa43ec25aa075"),
        "IP" : "113.183.149.127",
        "Product_Version" : "CMC_2.0",
        "Product_ID" : "HHFFHJRLAUHOZDBM1YWY291NM0DD7J40",
        "OS" : "Microsoft_Window_7",
        "virus" : "Adware:W32/Superfish",
        "Time" : ISODate("2017-01-18T10:22:55.356Z"),
        "city_name" : "",
        "location" : {
            "latitude" : 0.0,
            "longitude" : 0.0
        }
    }
    {
        "_id" : ObjectId("587f41ffb5ffa43ec25aa078"),
        "IP" : "27.76.109.254",
        "Product_Version" : "CMC_2.0",
        "Product_ID" : "UCOV8JY5YHKQ2B0HPCC0IM1S9T0ICWL7",
        "OS" : "Microsoft_Window_7",
        "virus" : "Backdoor:W32/BlackEnergy",
        "Time" : ISODate("2017-01-18T10:22:55.380Z"),
        "city_name" : "Ho Chi Minh City",
        "location" : {
            "latitude" : 10.75,
            "longitude" : 106.66667
        }
    }
    {
        "_id" : ObjectId("587f41ffb5ffa43ec25aa079"),
        "IP" : "42.116.189.121",
        "Product_Version" : "CMC_2.0",
        "Product_ID" : "3WKR7313ONV21OXNX1ZGDKG0A0CB89MH",
        "OS" : "Microsoft_Window_7",
        "virus" : "Trojan:W97M/MaliciousMacro",
        "Time" : ISODate("2017-01-18T10:22:55.440Z"),
        "city_name" : "Hanoi",
        "location" : {
            "latitude" : 21.0245,
            "longitude" : 105.84117
        }
    }
```

I use mapReduce to find all documents in date `("2017-01-18")`

```
var query = {};
query.map = function() {
    var key = new Date("2017-01-18");
    var value = {
        lat: this.location.latitude,
        lng: this.location.longitude,
    };

    emit(key, value);
};
query.reduce = function(key, values) {
    var reducedObject = {};

    values.forEach(function(value) {
        reducedObject.lat = value.lat;
        reducedObject.lng = value.lng;
    });

    return reducedObject;
};
query.out = {
    replace: "map_reduce"
};
query.verbose = true;

Msg.mapReduce(query, function(error, model, stats) {
    if (error) {
        require(path.join(__dirname, '../', 'ultis/logger.js'))().log('error', JSON.stringify(error));
        if (typeof callback === 'function') return callback(-2, null);
    } else {
        console.log('map reduce took %d ms', stats.processtime)

        model.find().exec(function(error, docs) {
            if (error) {
                require(path.join(__dirname, '../', 'ultis/logger.js'))().log('error', JSON.stringify(error));
                if (typeof callback === 'function') return callback(-2, null);
            } else {
                // if (typeof callback === 'function') return callback(null, docs);
                console.log(docs);
            }
        });
    }
});
```

I just have the result such as

```
map reduce took 855 ms
[ { _id: Wed Jan 18 2017 07:00:00 GMT+0700 (SE Asia Standard Time),
    value: { lat: 0, lng: 0 } } ]
```

I want to have all documents on date 2017-01-18.

**Question 1 : How to have all documents on date 2017-01-18?**

**Question 2 : Can mapReduce get value with key is an object?. I mean that I can get documents from date 2017-01-18 to date 2017-01-23. Image such as**

```
query.map = function() {
    var key = {};
        key.from = new Date("2017-01-18");
        key.to= new Date("2017-01-23");
    var value = {
        lat: this.location.latitude,
        lng: this.location.longitude,
    };

    emit(key, value);
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MapReduce is overkill for this task. You only need to construct a date range query that is from that start of `2017-01-18 00:00hrs` till `2017-01-18 23:59:59.999` and then use it in a **[`find()`](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#model_Model.find)** or **[`aggregate()`](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#model_Model.aggregate)**
pipeline query:

```
var start = new Date("2017-01-18");
start.setHours(0,0,0,0);

var end = new Date("2017-01-18");
end.setHours(23,59,59,999);

var query = { "Time": { "$gte": start, "$lte": end } };

Msg.find(query, function(error, docs) {
    if (error) {
        console.log(error);
    } else {
        console.log(docs);
    }
});
```

or using **[`aggregate()`](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#model_Model.aggregate)**

```
Msg.aggregate()
   .match(query)
   .exec(function(error, docs) {
        if (error) {
            console.log(error);
        } else {
            console.log(docs);
        }
    });
```

---

For your second question it's only a matter of changing the query date range to

```
var start = new Date("2017-01-18");  
var end = new Date("2017-01-23");

var query = { "Time": { "$gte": start, "$lte": end } };
```

Comment: I used to `find()` query before, but it isn't performance. I have about 5 millions documents and this query break because of timeout on response too long. If mapReduce can't use in case, I hope `aggregate()` would perfomance than `find()`. Thank you for your answer!